# What would be the best approach to design a dynamic query builder for realm.io?

Tags: android, realm

I am designing an "advanced filter" functionality for my Android app where I can multi-select several query parameters, depending on the parameter type sometimes it will be a union, sometimes an intersection, but always on one object type (with some nested objects).
Would anyone know of an elegant and generic way to design such a query builder?

My object looks like this:

public class DBDocument extends RealmObject {

```
@PrimaryKey
private int _id;
private String updatedAt;
private String name;
private String subject;
private int type;
private int senderId;
private String dateSent;
private int paymentStatus;
private String paymentDue;
private double invoiceAmount;
private String currency;
private String acknowledged;
private String fetched;
private String exported;
private int recipient;
private int addressId;
private String printed;
private boolean important;
private boolean hidden;
private int printMode;
private int printRule;
private RealmList<DBTag> tag = new RealmList<>();
private RealmList<DBComment> comment = new RealmList<>();
private RealmList<DBEvent> event = new RealmList<>();
```

...
}

Comment: How generic do you wish it to be? Introspection of classes is fairly expensive in Java, so a complete generic builder might be very slow. I'm not sure if it will help, but the Realm Browser for Android (https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/realm-browser) could give you some inspiration.

Comment: I have managed to do this using the realm.io query.beginGroup(); and query.endGroup(); to define each search section and chaining them using query.equalTo() (for intersection).